# fail2ban jail not working

Tags: debian, fail2ban

I am struggling to get a single jail working in fail2ban. Fail2ban seems
functional, and other jails are working. I have tried using `fail2ban-regexp`
and it seems to be matching multiple times, but nothing is happening in terms
of banning.

The filter looks like this:

```
/etc/fail2ban/filter.d$ more apache-xmlrpc.conf
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).*\/xmlrpc\.php.* HTTP\/.*
ignoreregex =
```

jail-local like this!

```
/etc/fail2ban/$ more jail-local.conf

[apache-xmlrpc]
enabled = true
port = http,https
filter = apache-xmlrpc
logpath = /var/log/apache*/*access.log
maxretry = 10
findtime = 600
bantime = 86400
```

And config dump like this:

```
['add', 'apache-xmlrpc', 'auto']
['set', 'apache-xmlrpc', 'addlogpath', '/var/log/apache2/ssl_access.log']
['set', 'apache-xmlrpc', 'addlogpath', '/var/log/apache2/access.log']
['set', 'apache-xmlrpc', 'addlogpath', '/var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log']
['set', 'apache-xmlrpc', 'maxretry', 10]
['set', 'apache-xmlrpc', 'addignoreip', '127.0.0.1/8']
['set', 'apache-xmlrpc', 'findtime', 600]
['set', 'apache-xmlrpc', 'bantime', 86400]
['set', 'apache-xmlrpc', 'addfailregex', '^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).*\\/xmlrpc\\.php.* HTTP\\/.*']
['set', 'apache-xmlrpc', 'addaction', 'iptables-multiport']
['set', 'apache-xmlrpc', 'actionban', 'iptables-multiport', 'iptables -I fail2ban-<name> 1 -s <ip> -j DROP']
['set', 'apache-xmlrpc', 'actionstop', 'iptables-multiport', 'iptables -D <chain> -p <protocol> -m multiport --dports <port> -j fail2ban-<name>\niptables -F fail2ban-<name>\niptables -X fail2ban-<name>']
['set', 'apache-xmlrpc', 'actionstart', 'iptables-multiport', 'iptables -N fail2ban-<name>\niptables -A fail2ban-<name> -j RETURN\niptables -I <chain> -p <protocol> -m multiport --dports <port> -j fail2ban-<name>']
['set', 'apache-xmlrpc', 'actionunban', 'iptables-multiport', 'iptables -D fail2ban-<name> -s <ip> -j DROP']
['set', 'apache-xmlrpc', 'actioncheck', 'iptables-multiport', 'iptables -n -L <chain> | grep -q fail2ban-<name>']
['set', 'apache-xmlrpc', 'setcinfo', 'iptables-multiport', 'protocol', 'tcp']
['set', 'apache-xmlrpc', 'setcinfo', 'iptables-multiport', 'name', 'apache-xmlrpc']
['set', 'apache-xmlrpc', 'setcinfo', 'iptables-multiport', 'chain', 'INPUT']
['set', 'apache-xmlrpc', 'setcinfo', 'iptables-multiport', 'port', 'http,https']
```

I've restarted (I've rebooted!). And still no luck.

Any ideas gratefully recieved.

Comment: Check your iptables rules to see if you have an accept rule that is overriding the fail2ban rules?

Comment: Not as far as I can see -- besides I am not getting things *in* the jail. There are no DROP rules in iptables.